# Let $(G,*)$ be an abelian group.
Prove that, for all $a,b \in G$, then $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ for three consecutive integers $n$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $(G,*)$ be an abelian group.
Prove that, for all $a,b \in G$, then $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ for three consecutive integers $n$.

How to bring $ab=ba$ to $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$? Any ideas?
Is it need to prove firstly $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for all integers $n$? Then the result follows for $n+1$ and $n+2$?

Comment: $(ab)^n=ab\cdot ab...\cdot ab=a\cdot a...\cdot a\cdot b\cdot b...\cdot b = a^nb^n$ because $G$ is abelian.

Comment: "for three consecutive integer n$".

Comment: What does the "for three consecutive integers $n$" mean...? In fact for all $n$ it holds that $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$  in an abelian group, which you can prove informally (see previous comment) or more formally by induction.

Comment: @MeesdeVries for all consecutive integers $n$ means holds for $n,n+1,n+2$.

Comment: It holds for all integers, $\{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...\}$, so you can pick any three of them. For example, $3920, 3921, 3922$ (but it's easier to prove if you pick $0, 1, 2$).

Comment: This seems like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly do you want to achive here?

Comment: I want to achive that $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ holds for all $a,b\in G$ and for three consecutive integers $n$. But, if I can show it by math induction that it's true for all integer $n$, it means that it holds for three consecutive integer $n$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to use induction over all $n$.

Without induction:

$ab=ab$,

$(ab)^{2} = (ab)(ab)=a(ba)b=a(ab)b=(aa)(bb)=a^{2}b^{2}$,

$(ab)^{3} = ((ab)(ab))(ab)=(a(ba)b)(ab)=(a(ab)b)(ab)=((aa)(bb))(ab)=(aa)((bb)(ab))=(aa)((b(ba)b))=(aa)((b(ab)b))=(aa)((ba)(bb))=((aa)(ba))(bb)=((aa)(ab))(bb)=((a^{2})(ab))(bb)=((a^{2}a)b))(bb)=(a^{3}b)(bb)=(a^{3}b)(b^{2})=a^{3}(bb^{2})=a^{3}b^{3}.$

Then $(ab)^{n} = a^{n}b^{n}$ for three consecutive integers, namely $n = 1,2$, $3$.

Comment: Is this approach correct since the tree consecutive integers are arbitrary?

Comment: The title in your question simply asks to show the statement is true for three consecutive integers given $G$ is abelian. At that point, yes the numbers can be arbitrary as long as they are consecutive.

Comment: Got it, thanks yow!

Comment: @user795084 You're welcome. Accept this as an answer to remove the question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 3):

The *converse* statement is much more interesting: let $n$, $n+1$ and $n+2$ be three consecutive integers $k$ with $(ab)^k=a^kb^k$.  From $a^{n+1} b^{n+1}  = (ab)^{n+1} = (ab)(ab)^n = aba^n b^n$ it follows $a^n b = b a^n$. A similar argument with $n$ replaced by $n+1$ yields
$a^{n+1} b = b a^{n+1}$. Now $a b = a b a^n a^{-n} = a a^n b a^{-n} = a^{n+1} b a^{-n} = b a^{n+1} a^{-n} = b a$. Hence $G$ must be abelian.

Comment: I have prove it. So, I asking the converse of this.

Comment: @user795084 have I not answered your question?

Comment: Yes @user795084 if you have proved this, then your original post must be a triviality (see Derek Luna's answer), since your proof must exhibit how you handle products of elements of a group. That is why I gave the answer above. But, if you have proved that already, great job!

Comment: @NickyHekster Thanks Sir. I'm very appreciate your attempt above.

Comment: You are welcome and keep asking questions!